# How do I inset faces so that it creates new edges and doesn't require manual vertex deleting

Tags: extrude

I've been trying to inset some faces, however I don't want all the edges to duplicate and new faces to be stretched along with the edges as per the pics below. Is there an easier way to do this? I I can scale them to where I need them, then delete all unwanted vertices and rejoin all the necessary faces, but this feels like bad practice? Is there a method the merges the convenience of extruding and scaling. All help is welcomed :)

Cheers,

[image: Original]

[image: takes adjacent edges with it when scaled]

[image: Extrude makes all the vertices I have to manually delete]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extrude inwards some faces, to do that you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Manifold*:

[image]

But if you want to keep a good topology you need to create some new edge loops (for example with the knife):

[image]

Actually a better practice is rather to extrude the other faces outwards (then scale the whole shape on one axis to keep it as thick as before):

[image]

Comment: yes thank you!!! this is what I'm looking for, much appreciated :)